# c++ ofstream fails to read a .txt

Tags: c++

So I am trying to copy a word by word from file1 to file2 , but my code fails in opening file2 (the output file)

```
void myFile::printWords(string inFile, string outFile)
{
ifstream file;
ofstream file2;
file.open(inFile);
file2.open(outFile);
if (!file.is_open() && !file2.is_open()){
    string word;
    while (!file.eof()){
        file >> word;
        file2 << word << '\n';
    }
}
else{
    cout << "error" << endl;
}
file.close();
file2.close();
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: i think you code is a problem: check for both file to be open is not implemented correctly

Comment: Oh gosh, I copied the check from another function and forget to remove the (!) ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that you only copy words, if both files **failed** to open, not if both of them **succeeded** to open:

```
if (!file.is_open() && !file2.is_open()){
```

Replace it with:

```
if (file.is_open() && file2.is_open()){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!file.is_open() && !file2.is_open())
```

Means if `file` is not open and `file2` is not open.  So you will try to read from the files if they are not open and is not you execute `cout << "error" << endl;`.

Your if condition should be

```
if (file.is_open() && file2.is_open())
```

Also if you want to copy one file to another than you can use

```
file2 << file.rdbuf();
```

Instead of a while loop.

Comment: I need Word by Word for another fun' , thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

`if (!file.is_open() && !file2.is_open())`

if file is not open and file2 is not open

this logic will not copy file to file2 if your testing to see if both files are not open.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

```
if (!file.is_open() && !file2.is_open()){
```

It should be

```
if (file.is_open() && file2.is_open()){
```

**Problem 2**

```
while (!file.eof()){
    file >> word;
    file2 << word << '\n';
}
```

That is wrong. It should be:

```
while ( file >> word ){
    file2 << word << '\n';
}
```

To understand why, see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

The tests of the form `!file.is_open()` shouldn't have the `not` operator and could be simplified even more by relying on the [`operator bool()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) member function. It's also rarely correct to loop on the `eof()` condition.

Taking those two things in mind I've rewritten your function, I think it's simpler and more correct this way.

```
void myFile::printWords(const string &inFile, const string &outFile)
{
    ifstream file(inFile);
    ofstream file2(outFile);
    if (file && file2) {
        string word;
        while (file >> word) {
            file2 << word << '\n';
        }
    } else {
        cout << "error" << endl;
    }
}
```

Note: the streams will be closed automatically when they're destroyed at the end of this function.